# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x008A53A1 в ConsoleApplication45.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, объекты

```
class mine {
public:
    int param = 5;

};

class firstcl :public mine {

};
class sec : public firstcl{
};

class third : public sec{
};
class fouth : public third{
};

int main()
{
    mine ***arr = new mine**[2];
    *arr[0] = new firstcl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: за это нужно увольнять )

Comment: На эту тему есть годная статья - [*Трехзвездочный программист* (англ)](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Прочитал статью, действительно четыре звезды https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_cycle.h. Правда это не с++, но занятно. Никогда не видел прежде.

Answer (score 2):

```
  mine ***arr = new mine**[2];
  *arr[0] = new firstcl;
```

Ваш массив является массивом указателей не на  указателей, а массивом указателей на (указателей на указатели).  Соответственно `*arr[0]`  это указатель на указатель, а `new firstcl` возвращает указатель на созданный обьект `firstcl()` 
Думаю вам нужен массив указателей на указатели

```
mine **arr = new mine*[2];
*arr[0] = new firstcl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr[0]` - неинициализированный указатель, содержащий мусор. `*arr[0]` - это применение оператора `*` к неинициализированному указателю. Порождает неопределенное поведение. Вот и все.

Comment: как это можно исправить?
я пока не понимаю